# How in R to add lines of text above column names in a dataframe and save as txt file

Tags: r

I'm using R to pull data from Adobe Analytics. The dataframe has column names and I am looking to add the following lines above the column names and save the file as a txt with the previous date: filename_yyyy-mm-dd.

I'm having issues adding the following above the column names:

## Product Cost template file (user: 400024375 ds_id: 2)

## Products COGS (e102)  Original Price (e103) Sale Price (e104) Purchase ID

These are the column names:
Date    Product Event 102   Event 103   Event 104   transactionID

Here is the final file should look like:

[image]

Comment: What does that mean "above" the column names? Where do you want to put them?

Comment: You can do this by first converting to a `flextable`, adding a header with `add_header` and then exporting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it (assuming your dataframe is named `your_data`):

```
line1 = '# Product Cost template file (user: 400024375 ds_id: 2)'
line2 = '# Products COGS (e102) Original Price (e103) Sale Price (e104) Purchase ID'
column_names = c( paste( line1, line2, 'Date', sep = '\n'), 'Product', 'Event 102', 'Event 103', 'Event 104', 'transactionID')

output = rbind( column_names, your_data)
write.table( output, "filename_yyyy-mm-dd.txt", sep="\t", quote = F, row.names = F, col.names = F )
```

Note that this assumes you do not yet have the column names in the data, which you seem to imply. If you do have the column names already in the first row, you just write `output[1, 1] = paste( line1, line2, output[1, 1], sep = '\n')` instead of the `rbind` line.

---

Alternatively, you can first write the first lines and then append the table:

```
line1 = '# Product Cost template file (user: 400024375 ds_id: 2)'
line2 = '# Products COGS (e102) Original Price (e103) Sale Price (e104) Purchase ID'
column_names = c( 'Date', 'Product', 'Event 102', 'Event 103', 'Event 104', 'transactionID')

names(your_data) = column_names 
file_name = "filename_yyyy-mm-dd.txt"
cat( line1, line2, file = file_name, sep="\n")
write.table( your_data, file_name, sep="\t", quote = F, row.names = F, col.names = T, append = T )
```

(Again, if you already have the column names, just remove the `column_names` parts.)